# Round up to a 10s in Dart

Tags: dart, pagination, rounding

I'm doing pagination and I'm wondering how I can take a number such as 11 and round it to 20.

Other cases:

```
1 should round to 10
501 should round to 510
10 should round to 10
```

Basically I have cards and there are 10 cards per page and so if there are 11 cards there should be 2 pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To round a number up to a multiple of some factor, you can do:

```dart
/// Round [number] up to a multiple of [factor].
///
/// The [factor] must be greater than zero.
int roundUp(int number, int factor) {
  if (factor < 1) throw RangeError.range(factor, 1, null, "factor");
  number += factor - 1;
  return number - (number % factor);
}
```

There is a corresponding `roundDown` which you can defined `roundUp` in terms of:

```dart
int roundDown(int number, int factor) {
  if (factor < 1) throw RangeError.range(factor, 1, null, "factor");
  return number - (number % factor);
}
int roundUp(int number, int factor) => roundDown(number + (factor - 1), factor);
```

This rounds towards plus/minus infinity. If you want to round towards/away from zero instead, you can use:

```
int roundTowardsZero(int number, int factor) {
  if (factor < 1) throw RangeError.range(factor, 1, null, "factor");
  return number - number.remainder(factor);
}
int roundAwayFromZero(int number, int factor) => 
    roundTowardsZero(number + number.sign * (factor - 1), factor);
```

Because this approach uses only integers, it's relatively safe from precision loss, but it can overflow at the very end of the integer range (or if you use very, very large factors). If you want to be safe against that, we need to add a check for whether `number + factor - 1` overflows. In most practical uses, that won't matter.

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is:

```
var test = 11;
print((test / 10).ceil() * 10); // 20
```

Dividing the number by 10 (in this case it's 11) will result in 1.1.

When you do `(1.1).ceil()`, you will get 2.

Now you multiply by 10 to get it to a power of 10.

Answer (score 2):

```dart
var data = 12.62;
print(data.ceil());
```

Will output

```dart
13
```